# Setting edge attributes conditionally in list-column graphs using R igraph and dplyr (purrr)

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, purrr

I have a dataframe with a series of `igraph` objects in list-column format. I would like to conditionally set the edge color attribute.

I've included the `dput` output for a sample version of the actual dataframe (very large, thousands of graphs) containing just three graphs. It's still long, so I've put it at the bottom of this post and I'll explain a couple of the ideas I've tried so far.

First attempt was multiple uses of `mutate` and `map` using the `purrr` package.

```
sampleColored <- sampleGraphs %>% mutate(map(graph, function(x) 
E(x)[weights == 0]$color = "blue")) %>% mutate(map(graph, function(x)
    E(x)[weights < 0]$color = "red"))  %>% mutate(map(graph, function(x)
    E(x)[weights > 0]$color = "green"))
```

No error messages, but the command

```
 shortPlots <- sampleColored %>%
 mutate(plots = map(graph, function(x) plot(x, layout=layout.circle,
     vertex.size=20,                                                          
     edge.curved=TRUE)))
```

produced nice graphs with all edges colored grey.

Likewise with my second attempt where I created an `edgeColor` function and used a single `map` call.

```
edgecolor <- function(x) {
E(x)[weights == 0]$color <- "blue"
E(x)[weights < 0]$color <- "red"
E(x)[weights > 0]$color <- "green"
return(E(x))
}
sampleColored <- sampleGraphs %>% mutate(map(graph, function(x) edgecolor(x)))
```

No error and grey edges. Dropping the `mutate` command gives rise to the error message:

```
Error in as.numeric(n): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

I'm confident that this is possible and I simply don't have the understanding to get to the correct syntax. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks for looking.

Here's the `sampleGraph` `dput`:

```
sampleGraphs <- structure(list(ID = 997:1000, graph = list(structure(list(5, 
TRUE, c(0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 4, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 
1, 4, 2), c(1, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 
3, 0, 2, 3, 4), c(0, 14, 10, 3, 1, 17, 15, 6, 2, 12, 7, 19, 
16, 4, 9, 13, 8, 5, 11, 18), c(1, 2, 16, 8, 0, 12, 4, 5, 
14, 17, 9, 11, 10, 15, 7, 18, 3, 6, 19, 13), c(0, 4, 8, 12, 
16, 20), c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
    structure(list(name = c("3", "0", "2", "4", "1")), .Names = "name"), 
    structure(list(weights = c(3L, -4L, 4L, -3L, 43L, 8L, 
    4L, 14L, 1L, 55L, 2L, 22L, 26L, 64L, 9L, 2L, 13L, -12L, 
    25L, 16L)), .Names = "weights")), <environment>), class = "igraph"), 
structure(list(5, TRUE, c(0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
0, 4, 0, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 0), c(3, 3, 4, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 0, 
4, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1), c(19, 11, 0, 13, 17, 4, 
1, 6, 3, 18, 16, 2, 10, 5, 7, 9, 8, 12, 14, 15), c(17, 3, 
10, 8, 19, 18, 5, 12, 11, 4, 7, 14, 0, 1, 16, 15, 13, 6, 
2, 9), c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20), c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20), list(
    c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
    structure(list(name = c("2", "0", "1", "3", "4")), .Names = "name"), 
    structure(list(weights = c(4L, -4L, 25L, 22L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, -3L, 55L, 2L, 9L, 16L, 43L, 14L, 64L, 13L, 1L, -12L, 
    8L, 26L)), .Names = "weights")), <environment>), class = "igraph"), 
structure(list(5, TRUE, c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 0, 0, 3, 4), c(1, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 
2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3), c(0, 17, 16, 5, 8, 6, 10, 
1, 7, 14, 2, 12, 18, 11, 9, 3, 4, 13, 15, 19), c(8, 7, 18, 
4, 0, 14, 11, 13, 17, 6, 9, 15, 16, 10, 2, 19, 5, 1, 12, 
3), c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20), c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20), list(
    c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
    structure(list(name = c("4", "0", "3", "2", "1")), .Names = "name"), 
    structure(list(weights = c(43L, 4L, 9L, 16L, 25L, 64L, 
    -4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, -11L, 26L, -3L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 55L, 13L, 
    14L, 22L)), .Names = "weights")), <environment>), class = "igraph"), 
structure(list(5, TRUE, c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 1, 
3, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3), c(4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 
3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 4), c(15, 14, 9, 0, 5, 10, 
18, 1, 16, 12, 7, 2, 11, 3, 6, 19, 8, 13, 4, 17), c(5, 16, 
11, 8, 15, 12, 3, 13, 14, 10, 6, 4, 9, 18, 7, 17, 0, 1, 2, 
19), c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20), c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20), list(
    c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
    structure(list(name = c("1", "4", "0", "2", "3")), .Names = "name"), 
    structure(list(weights = c(1L, 13L, -4L, 14L, 3L, 64L, 
    26L, -11L, -3L, 22L, 43L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 25L, 4L, 8L, 
    55L, 4L)), .Names = "weights")), <environment>), class = "igraph"))),     class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("ID", 
"graph"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Thanks to @paqmo for suggestions. I needed to use mutate to redefine the `graph` list-column variable.

```
edgecolor <- function(x) {
  E(x)[weights == 0]$color <- "#FF000000"
  E(x)[weights < 0]$color <- "red"
  E(x)[weights > 0]$color <- "green"
  return(E(x)$color)
}
sampleColored <- sampleGraphs %>% mutate(graph = map(graph, function(x) 
  set_edge_attr(x, "color", value = edgecolor(x))))

par(mfrow = c(2,2), mar = c(0,0,0,0))
samplePlots <- sampleColored %>%
     mutate(plots = map(graph, function(x) plot(x, layout=layout.circle,
       vertex.size=20,                                                          
       edge.curved=TRUE)))
```

generates the same image as @paqmo.

Answer (score 2):

Using `set_edge_attr` rather than `igraph`'s idiomatic `E()` edge function helps. I had to revise the `sampleGraph` list to a simple list of graphs, upgraded to the newer version of `igraph`, but this works:

```
graphs <- sampleGraphs$graph
graphs <- lapply(graphs, function(x) upgrade_graph(x)) #making a simple list of graphs

edgecolor <- function(x) {
  E(x)[weights == 0]$color <- "blue"
  E(x)[weights < 0]$color <- "red"
  E(x)[weights > 0]$color <- "green"
  return(E(x)$color)
} #The function now returns a list of colors conditional on statements

#Pass the function to the "values" argument of "set_edge_attr"

graphs_colored <- graphs %>% map(., function(x) set_edge_attr(x, "color", value = edgecolor(x)))

par(mfrow = c(2,2), mar = c(0,0,0,0))
shortPlots <- graphs_colored %>%
 map(., function(x) plot(x, 
                         layout=layout.circle,
                         vertex.size=20,                                                          
                         edge.curved=TRUE,
                         edge.arrow.size = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Almost! And the images are just want. Nice job with the par(). But I need to keep working with the list-column in the dataframe as I need the other identifying information. I changed the function to match yours, returning `E(x)$color`, and changed the `map` function to `map(graph, function(x) set_edge_attr(x, "color", value = edgecolor(x)))` and get the `Error in as.numeric(n): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'` error again.

Comment: I did try `sampleGraphs$graph <- lapply(sampleGraphs$graph, function(x) upgrade_graph(x))` and got the same error. I might play around randomly with unlist() or unnest(). What version of igraph are you using? I just installed last week and its 1.0.1 for R on Mac. Thanks!

Comment: I also tried `sampleColored <- sampleGraphs %>% mutate(graph = map(graph, function(x) upgrade_graph(x))) %>% 
                                         map(graph, function(x) set_edge_attr(x, "color", value = edgecolor(x)))`, similar to lappy above but more dplyerish. Same error.